# Why is this regex code not working

Tags: python, regex, django, django-views, django-urls

Working on a Django app

Here's my urls.py

```
urlpattterns = [url(r'^(?P<leagueId>[0-9]+)/(?P<year>[0-9]+)/(?P<team>[\S]+)/$', views.team_detail, name="team_detail"),]
```

An example url would be along the lines of:

```
http://localhost:8000/123456/2017/Johnny%20Rocket/
```

I tried playing around with Pythex, but I couldn't get the urls to match

Note: The variables passed are /{number}/{year}/{name}

The name can consist of alphanumeric characters and whitespaces.

Comment: But `%20` is an encoding of whitespace... Use `.+` instead.

Comment: I guess a lot of traffic is coming in from tags other than [django]. Django will extract the url path and cut of the first slash before the string is matched against the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character class `\S` matches anything except whitespace, and `%20` is decoded to a space before it is matched against the regex.

To match alphanumerical characters and whitespace, you can use `[\w\s]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following regex:

```
r"(?P<leagueId>\d+)/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<team>[^/]+)/$"
```

A few small changes:

- took out the ^ which means beginning of line
- changed the [0-9] to \d

But the big one being the  section.  I like to use negative character classes.  You basically want to match everything up to the next

```
/
```

And that is what

```
[^/]+
```

will do for you.

You may want to limit the year to a range like:

```
\d{2,4}
```

Comment: In the context of Django, adding a slash to the start is actually incorrect. The path is extracted, decoded, and the first slash is cut off before the string is matched against the regex.